# code is working but with a 'DeprecationWarning' -scipy.stats

Tags: python, csv, numpy, statistics, scipy

I wrote this code to calculate the mode and standard deviation for a large sample:

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import scipy.stats as sp
import math

r=open('stats.txt', 'w') #file with results
r.write('Data File'+'\t'+ 'Mode'+'\t'+'Std Dev'+'\n')
f=open('data.ls', 'rb') #file with the data files

for line in f:
    dataf=line.strip()
    data=csv.reader(open(dataf, 'rb'))
    data.next()
    data_list=[]
    datacol=[]
    data_list.extend(data)
    for rows in data_list:
            datacol.append(math.log10(float(rows[73])))
    m=sp.mode(datacol)
    s=sp.std(datacol)
    r.write(dataf+'\t'+str(m)+'\t'+str(s)+'\n')
    del(datacol)
    del(data_list)
```

Which is working well -I think! However after I run the code there is an error message on my terminal and I am wondering if anybody can tell me what it means?

```
 /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py:1328: DeprecationWarning:     scipy.stats.std is deprecated; please update your code to use numpy.std.
    Please note that:
    - numpy.std axis argument defaults to None, not 0
    - numpy.std has a ddof argument to replace bias in a more general manner.
      scipy.stats.std(a, bias=True) can be replaced by numpy.std(x,
      axis=0, ddof=0), scipy.stats.std(a, bias=False) by numpy.std(x, axis=0,
      ddof=1).
  ddof=1).""", DeprecationWarning)
/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py:1304: DeprecationWarning: scipy.stats.var is deprecated; please update your code to use numpy.var.
Please note that:
    - numpy.var axis argument defaults to None, not 0
    - numpy.var has a ddof argument to replace bias in a more general manner.
      scipy.stats.var(a, bias=True) can be replaced by numpy.var(x,
      axis=0, ddof=0), scipy.stats.var(a, bias=False) by var(x, axis=0,
      ddof=1).
  ddof=1).""", DeprecationWarning)
/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py:420: DeprecationWarning: scipy.stats.mean is deprecated; please update your code to use numpy.mean.
Please note that:
    - numpy.mean axis argument defaults to None, not 0
    - numpy.mean has a ddof argument to replace bias in a more general manner.
      scipy.stats.mean(a, bias=True) can be replaced by numpy.mean(x,
axis=0, ddof=1).
  axis=0, ddof=1).""", DeprecationWarning)
```

Comment: The problem is in `scipy/stats`, not in the code you show

Comment: @imkost so from what you see, is it something I need to worry about?

Comment: my mistake, sorry. The error is not in `scipy/stats`. I guess something wrong with `data.ls`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are [deprecation warnings](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.DeprecationWarning), which usually mean that your code will work, but may stop working in a future release.

Currently you have this line `s=sp.std(datacol)`. It looks like the warning suggests using `numpy.std()` instead of `scipy.stats.std()` Making this change could make this warning go away.

If you don't care about the deprecation warning and want to use your code as is, you can suppress it with the [warnings](http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html) module. For example, if you have a function `fxn()` that generates a DeprecationWarning, you can wrap it like this:

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    fxn()  #this function generates DeprecationWarnings
```

Comment: Exactly. There were some comments on the numpy/scipy lists about inconstencies between packages such as different default arguments for the `var`, `std`... functions/methods.

Answer (score 4):

The `DeprecationWarnings` don't prevent your code to run properly, they are just warnings that the code you are using will soon be deprecated and that you should update it to the proper syntax.

In this particular case, it stems from inconstencies between NumPy and SciPy on the default arguments for the `var`, `std`... functions/methods. In order to clean things up, it was decided to drop the functions from `scipy.stats` and use their NumPy counterparts instead.

Of course, just dropping the functions would upset some users whose code would suddenly fail to work. So, the SciPy devs decided to include a `DeprecationWarning` for a couple of releases, which should leave enough time for everybody to update their code.

In your case, you should use check the docstring of `scipy.stats.std` on your system to see what defaults they're using, and follow the warning instructions on how to modify your code accordingly.